# Adobe Acrobat and WebDAV

Tags: adobe, webdav, acrobat

I am trying to open and edit (add annotation) and save the PDF to an IISWebDAV repository.
I am using Acrobat Pro 9.0 and IIS 5.0 on XP SP2.

1. I need to be able to open the Acrobat programmatically from a Winform Application.
   I tried using Process.Start(url), but it opens the PDF in the browser document.
   Tried the following setting in Acrobat, but in vain.
   http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/06/17/disable-pdf-from-opening-in-web-browser-ie-firefox-opera-safari/

Tried the following code, but it opens the command prompt and doesn't open Acrobat.
 string url = "http://localhost/SampleWebDAV/Root/TestDoc100.doc";
 Process p = new Process();
 p.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMSPEC");
 p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c \"start \"" + url + "\"";
 p.Start();

2. Acrobat doesn't issue a LOCK/UNLOCK WebDAV command.
   Acrobat 9.0 release notes say that it supports WebDAV, but if I intercept the request with fiddler, I can see that only GET, PROPFIND and PUT commands are happening. I can't see LOCK and UNLOCK commands.

Thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

I am updating the result of my research.

1. Process.Open() can not be used to open an Acrobat file from a web/wendav URL
   The same result can be seen if you try to pass the path to the Actobat.exe. Only the local machine paths can be given.

I evaluated many third party tool, but nobody has this functionality to open adobe from a Url.

2. But Adobe ActiveX component can be used to view the component even from a WebDAV/Web location.
   You just need to set the URL accordingly
   But this component doesn't allow you to modify the PDF like adding an annotation etc.

I solved my issue by downloading the file to a local directory and then opening using Process.Start().